# Writing an hashcode function

Tags: java

I want to write a Hashcode function for my class. The equals method is already existing. What could serve as a good `hashcode()` for below class having mentioned fields.

```
public class ReservationSHC extends AuditableModel {
    /** The log instance for this class * */
    private static Log log = Log.getLog("RESERVATION");

    private Long id;
    private String shc;
    private boolean systemGenerated;
    private boolean notifyableLoadOrDGR;
    private Integer versionId;
    private String ownerCarrierCode;
    private String shcDesc;
    private String shcCategory;

    private CargoRecord cargoRecord;
    private ShipmentReservation shipmentReservation;
    private Set additionalDataElements;
    private boolean autoGenerated;
```

`Equals()` method is already existing for the class.

```
public boolean equals(Object arg0) {
    if (arg0 instanceof ReservationSHC) {
        ReservationSHC reservationSHC = (ReservationSHC) arg0;
        if (reservationSHC.getShc().equals(this.shc)) {
            return true;
        }
    } else if(arg0 instanceof String) {
        String tempShc = (String) arg0;
        if (tempShc.equals(this.shc)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return super.equals(arg0);
}
```

Also, I don't see any @override annotation on the equals method. Is it getting overridden??

Comment: The general rule is that if `equals` returns true then `hashcode` has to return true as well. We can't really tell u more without knowing the whole class.

Comment: You shouldnt put such comments into your question body. The question is the question, and answers/comments go separately ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, just use your IDE to generate the equals() and hashCode() methods selecting the relevant fields.

In this case, it looks like only **shc** is relevant to equality of objects, so these will be the methods ([as generated by intelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/generating-code.html) )

```
import java.util.Objects;
.
.
.
private String shc;
.
.

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    Hello hello = (Hello) o;
    return shc.equals(hello.shc);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(shc);
}
```

In your case i think you should re-evaluate the equals method too. Equating the object to the string seems incorrect.

Comment: Also, in equals, both are string type which are getting equated.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of the annotation `@Override` is only meant to give you compiler warnings in case you do something wrong.

Example: if you changed your signature to

```
@Override
public boolean equals(String other)
```

then the compiler would know tell you that "no, this `equals()` method doesn't override anything" (because it uses `String` for its argument, but it must be `other`.

And note: your `equals()` implementation is wrong. When any `x.equals(y)` is true, then `y.equals(x)` needs to be true, too. And your idea to directly compare against Strings violates that condition. Example:

```
yourObject.equals("some"); // could give true, when yourObject.shc is "some"
```

but

```
"some".equals(yourObject); // will never be true, because yourObject isn't a string
```

Finally, you are comparing only one field, so that field should go into both methods, as written in the other answer!

Comment: Sorry, I still didn't understand how the equals is wrong. Could you use the equals() in question and elaborate pls.

Comment: @user1896796 I added an example to my answer. This is also *nicely* documented in the javadoc for Object equals().

Comment: okay . But in this case, `this.shc` and `obj.getShc()` would always be a string.

Comment: @user1896796 Again: the implementation within java.lang.String doesn't know **your** class. It will go "if other is String, then compare strings, else: false".